# Return Date Object when Aggregating by Hour

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoengine

I am trying to aggregate records by reducing datetime to hours. Is there a way to do it in mongoengine and to save the field type?

My data is:

```
{'spent': 7, 'time_started': datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 21, 16, 2, 16, 661000)}
{'spent': 3, 'time_started': datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 21, 17, 8, 5, 415000)}
{'spent': 3, 'time_started': datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 21, 15, 52, 45, 917000)}
{'spent': 1, 'time_started': datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 21, 16, 42, 32, 313000)}
{'spent': 8, 'time_started': datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 21, 16, 35, 46, 863000)}
{'spent': 5, 'time_started': datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 21, 15, 55, 1, 217000)}
{'spent': 10, 'time_started': datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 20, 17, 41, 50, 5000)}
```

Here is what i come out with so far:

```
pipeline =[
    'match': {
        "time_started": {
            "$gte": datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 21, 0, 0, 0),
            }
        },
    'project': {
        "spent": "$spent",
         "time_started": {"$dateToString": {
                "format": "%Y-%m-%dT%H:00:00",
                "date": "$time_started"
            }}
        },
    'group': {
        "_id": {
            "time_started": "$time_started",
            },
        "spent_total": {"$sum": "$spent"}
        }
    ]
```

It works well, but "time_started" is a string in the result, while i need datetime, like this:

```
{'spent_total': 16, 'time_started': datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 21, 16, 0, 0)}
{'spent_total': 3, 'time_started': datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 21, 17, 0, 0)}
{'spent_total': 8, 'time_started': datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 21, 15, 0, 0)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use "date math" with the objects instead and then they will be retained as BSON date types and translate to the native type in your driver:

```
pipeline = [
    { '$match': {
        "time_started": {
            "$gte": datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 21, 0, 0, 0),
            }
        }
     }},
     { "$group": {
        "_id": {
             "$add": [
                 { "$subtract": [
                     { "$subtract": [
                         "$time_started", datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1) 
                     ]},
                     { "$mod": [
                         { "$subtract": [
                             "$time_started", datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1) 
                         ]},
                         1000 * 60 * 60
                     ]}
                 ]},
                 datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)
             ]
        },
        "spent_total": { "$sum": "$spent" }
     }}
 ];

Class._get_collection().aggregate(pipeline);
```

Where the basic concept is that when you subtract the "epoch date" from the value of a date field then the value returned is numeric. Here you apply a modulo **`$mod`** to work out the remainder from the milliseconds in an hour and round the date down to the hour.

Then the reverse is true when you "add" the "epoch date" to the number, then it returns a new `Date` object equal to the represented value in milliseconds.

Since it is just a date already, the driver treats it accordingly and there is no need to translate. Much better than using strings or other operators. Also note, you don't need a `$project` and just apply such a conversion directly to the `_id` in `$group`, and that will even speed things up.

Comment: thank you, this works! far from obvious, but really creative! ))

Comment: @funkifunki Lets call it an undocumented "feature". But this is how "math" with date objects behaves in the aggreation pipeline. Now you know.